# limit of a differential equation

Tags: limits

Consider equation below
$$
[-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac{l(l+1)}{x^2}+\frac{x^2}4+\frac s x-\frac E \omega]\phi(x)=0 \tag{1}
$$
Assume that we want to find solution of $\phi$ for $x \to 0$ and $x\to \infty$. I have read somewhere that if $x\to 0$  equation (1) reduces to 
$$
[-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac{l(l+1)}{x^2}]f_0(x)=0 \tag{2}
$$
where the solutions are
$$
f_0(x)=x^{(l+1)} \,\; and\,\; f_0(x)=x^{-l} \tag{3}
$$

and for $x\to \infty$ equation (1) becomes
$$
[-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac{x^2}4]f_{\infty}(x)=0 \tag{4}
$$
where the solutions are
$$
f_{\infty}(x)=e^{\frac{x^2}4}\,\;and \,\;f_{\infty}(x)=e^{\frac{-x^2}4} \tag{5}
$$
actually I cant understand how it reached these solution, Can you help me to find?

Comment: One could argue that in the limit $x \rightarrow 0$, the $\\frac{l(l+1)}{x^2}$ dominates $x^2/4 + s/x-E/\omega$ and similarly for $x \rightarrow \infty$ but I'm not sure how to make this into a rigorous argument.

Comment: Sounds similar to some boundary layer theory arguments. That may be a good place to start looking.